# How to auto detect and validate date format in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, matplotlib

I have somewhat of an interesting situation. I am making a program that intends to plot graphs using the text files generated by Whatsapp for each chat with the 'Export Chat Option'
The file looks like this :

```
4/9/21, 16:40 - Speaker A: how was it ?
4/9/21, 16:40 - Speaker B: Yeah...
4/9/21, 16:41 - Speaker B: Easy...
```

and so on. For this I need to parse the dates in their correct format, which I wont know, and the program wont be editable, as it is intended as GUI for normal people. It has to work out of the box.

The problem is that Whatsapp on different Company smartphones, exports the file using different date formats (I know, weird)

So the same file if generated by Speaker B may have differently formatted dates as opposed to the one by Speaker A. The intention is for the program to work from anyone's text file.

```
9/4/21, 16:40 - Speaker A: how was it ?
9/4/21, 16:40 - Speaker B: Yeah...
9/4/21, 16:41 - Speaker B: Easy...
```

Now I cant use any of the normal validation code blocks I find online, as they offer alternatives if the date is wrong like `13/12/20` cant be `%m/%d/%y`, so it would default to the one that makes sense, and in some other places it would accept `%m/%d/%y` resulting in differently parsed date formats for the same file which i dont want as it'll mess up the graph.

So i have to know for sure which date format it is. Note that there can be hudreds if not thousands of dates which fit both formats in the same file. What is the best way to do this?

I am using matplotlib and pandas for plotting, and am open to any solution.

Edit : The only way I thought this was possible was to loop over the entire file with one format, and if it throws an error it had to be the other one. then loop over the entire file again to get the actual dates. But I thought this was rather inefficient, and wanted to know if anyone had a better alternative

Comment: Could you pull out the month number of every message, then check if any of these is larger than 12? this only works if you have enough messages however

Comment: I would also check for plausibility. Compare 4/9/20, 4/10/20, 5/8/20 with 4/9/20, 4/10/20, 3/11/20.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
datetime.datetime.now()
```

For retrieve the year/month/day hour:minutes:second format or you can also use it to something like

```py
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%D/%M/%Y") #format something like %H for hour %D for day %M for month %Y for year %M for minutes %S for seconds
```

Comment: Sorry, but this has nothing to do with it